# eclipse: keyboard short cut not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, git, eclipse, commit

In eclipse - helios (Ubuntu 10.04), the git commit menu displays a keyboard short cut also - Ctrl+Alt+C. But this key combination will not activate this menu. How to use the keyboard short cut for git commits?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts are scary. CTRL+ALT+C is already mapped to [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529/useful-eclipse-features/20561#20561).

Search through `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys` to [remove this mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461743/is-there-anyway-to-modify-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse).

Comment: I now see that CTRL+ALT+C is mapped to many different actions. It says that it is mapped to git commit under Git category in Windows. So what does it mean? Apparently this means that this mapping takes effect under certain conditions, right? What is that?

Comment: @suresh The condition is that every other C-A-c is disabled.